# Rich Text in a VB6 text box

Tags: vb6, richtextbox

Does anyone know if there is a way outside of using a 3rd Party text box control, to enter HTML into a VB6 text box.

I havent found anything online.

Comment: Can you get away with using an RTF text box and converting the output to HTML? That's an approach we've used recently which has worked well for our requirements. I can supply more details if it's any use

Comment: There is a RTF Box in VB6?

Comment: Apologies, I was just about to update my answer after I noticed you were using VB6.

Comment: @kevin - Thanks please post as an answer so I can accept! I found a Microsoft RTF Control

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? You can also use the web browser control if you are trying to render html.

Comment: @jac there are 2 applications, an asp/asp.net application that generates an email in HTML format and a VB6 that needs to read it. We need the VB6 app to read the HTML. The user may be able to edit the email and re-save it in the database or they may just view it.

Comment: The web browser control would probably do a nice job of displaying the email. But while you can directly type into the browser control, you can't directly type html, so you would have to add formatting tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully you'll be able to make use of this. We're doing it in .Net to allow a simple edit control on forms to send formatted emails. As such we have a RTF text box with a custom menu for creating the text, then we extract the RTF, convert it to HTML and add it as HTML content as the body of an email. The RTF to HTML conversion uses the code from this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27431/Writing-Your-Own-RTF-Converter

Here's the wrapper code we use to tie this together - it simply takes an RTF input and directly returns an HTML output:

```
Imports Itenso.Rtf
Imports Itenso.Rtf.Support
Imports Itenso.Rtf.Parser
Imports Itenso.Rtf.Interpreter
Imports Itenso.Rtf.Converter.Image
Imports Itenso.Rtf.Converter.Html
Imports Itenso.Sys.Application
Namespace Email
  Public Class RtfToHtml

    Public Function Convert(inText As String) As String
      Dim struct = ParseRtf(inText)
      Dim doc = InterpretRtf(struct)
      Return ConvertHtml(doc)
    End Function


    Private Function ParseRtf(inText As String) As IRtfGroup
      Dim structureBuilder As New RtfParserListenerStructureBuilder
      Dim parser = New RtfParser(structureBuilder) With {.IgnoreContentAfterRootGroup = True}
      Dim source = New RtfSource(inText)
      parser.Parse(source)
      Return structureBuilder.StructureRoot
    End Function

    Private Function InterpretRtf(rtfStructure As IRtfGroup) As IRtfDocument
      Dim settings = New RtfInterpreterSettings With {.IgnoreDuplicatedFonts = True, .IgnoreUnknownFonts = True}
      Return RtfInterpreterTool.BuildDoc(rtfStructure, settings)
    End Function

    Private Function ConvertHtml(document As IRtfDocument) As String
      Dim settings As New RtfHtmlConvertSettings With {.Title = "Notification Of Shipment",
                                                       .IsShowHiddenText = False,
                                                       .UseNonBreakingSpaces = True}
      Dim converter = New RtfHtmlConverter(document, settings)
      'converter.StyleConverter = New RtfEmptyHtmlStyleConverter
      Return converter.Convert
    End Function

  End Class
End Namespace
```

Depending on your application you could simply wrap this up in an assembly and call it from VB6. We've done this in the past and it's reasonably straightforward. Again, more info if you think it might be useful to you

Comment: I should point out that the library I linked to can accomplish a lot more than the very simple use I'm putting it to, and the example I attached above just represents this basic use that we are making of it

Comment: Thanks @kevin. I will look into this. I need to make sure the company can use 3rd party tools like that.